# Why keyboard layout switch keys don't work correctly for the specific English/Persian combination?

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout, input-language

I'm using Lubuntu 20.04 with LXQt desktop environment. I need to have 2 keyboard layouts (English/Persian) and be able to switch between them. I turned off input methods and am using only the default Lubuntu Keyboard Settings to set `Win+Space` keys for changing layouts. The problem is that it works for switching from English to Persian but when I want to switch back, actually `LSHIFT+SPACE` keys can do the job and `Win+Space` doesn't work at all. I tried it with other layout combinations like English/France or English/German and they all work well both ways. I even tried to read and compare layout files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` directory but found no clue.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce that on Ubuntu. Sounds as a Lubuntu bug which you should bring to the Lubuntu developers. Maybe here: https://phab.lubuntu.me

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson That's true. In fact, I was myself using Ubuntu 20.04 without any problems.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Is there any way for me to use Ubuntu 20.04 layout files instead of Lubuntu ones? How can I acquire those layout files? Is there any way to download them?

Comment: It's the same files. :) They are provided by the `xkb-data` package on all Ubuntu flavors. So the issue you describe seems to be something with the Lubuntu/LXQt desktop.

Comment: I have confirmed this does not work, but only with certain layouts. Afghani has the same problem, as an example. There is no problem, on the other hand, with French, for example. I see no upstream bugs related to this. If you could file a bug with `ubuntu-bug lxqt-config-input`, I'll get to work on triaging it and hopefully getting it resolved.

Comment: FYI:   wxl is a Lubuntu *developer*, so it reached the right eyes... but we need it on a bug report so it can be chased up & tracked (launchpad.net where it may go upstream too; I'll provide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs or for Lubuntu specifically you can refer to https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/bugs/)

Comment: Bug Reports are offtopic here on Ask Ubuntu.  We've closed this as such - per the Lubuntu Team they've confirmed this is something that needs a bug filed, so closed as offtopic here.

Comment: Thanks so much @wxl! I just posted a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxqt-config/+bug/1912841). `lxqt-config-input` was not an ubuntu package so I reported the bug for `lxqt-config` which I guess is inclusive of the input package.

Comment: @SaeedAhadian ah yes I neglected to remember that bugs are filed against source packages not binaries (I seem to spend more time working on bugs than reporting them these days!). Thank you so much for doing that. I'll get working on it shortly and will report my findings on the bug report, which you'll get notices of. Thanks again!

Comment: I have the same problem (English <-> Bulgarian). I have tried some input managers but the problem was not fixed.

Comment: There is a manual fix suggested:

https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-20-04-lxqt-0-14-keyboard-layout-does-not-switch/1551/5

dinya Feb '21

Have the same troubles with fresh LTS Lubuntu 20.04.2. lxqt-config-input: any chosen element in “Keyboard Layouts → Key to change layout” doesn’t work properly (always resets to None).

I edited [Keyboard] section in ~/.config/lxqt/session.conf manually (options param was added):

[Keyboard]
options=grp:lalt_lshift_toggle